# ribbon.eureka.enabled=true not working in Zuul Gateway

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

application.properties :-

```
spring.application.name=zuulgateway
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
zuul.routes.clientone.path=/clientone/**
zuul.routes.clientone.service-id=clientone
ribbon.eureka.enabled=true
#clientone.ribbon.listOfServers = http://localhost:8001
zuul.ignored-services=*
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
server.port=8000
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

build.gradle :-

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul', version: '2.2.7.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client', version: '3.0.2'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-config', version: '3.0.3'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap', version: '3.0.2'
    
}

ext {
    springCloudVersion = '2020.0.0'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

Main class :-

```
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class ZuulGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ZuulGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

When I try to access endpoint present in clientone service I'm getting error like

```
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: clientone
```

Error :-

```
021-04-04 20:19:30.811 DEBUG 24288 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] o.s.c.n.zuul.filters.SimpleRouteLocator  : route matched=ZuulRoute{id='clientone', path='/clientone/**', serviceId='clientone', url='null', stripPrefix=true, retryable=null, sensitiveHeaders=[], customSensitiveHeaders=false, }
2021-04-04 20:19:30.816  WARN 24288 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   : Error during filtering

com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:198) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:173) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:119) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:2.2.7.RELEASE]
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:117) ~[zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
```

When I uncomment `clientone.ribbon.listOfServers` in properties file getting success response. Then what is the use of this `ribbon.eureka.enabled=true` property if I provide list of servers.